# Inconsistent "Upload Image" box

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat, uploader

The upload image box shows an animated activity indicator when you upload an image on SO. However, in chat, when you upload an image, it just says "uploading image..."

This is inconsistent and just threw me off for a second. Please fix this by adding both the indicator and the text to both upload dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting; I mainly just <s>stole that code</s> *made use of existing assets*, so the discrepancy is unexpected - unless that was added after I branched it.

Comment: Is this "status-completed" yet?

Comment: @moshe - no; busy elsewhere today

Comment: Okay, jus' askin' . Get to it when you can.

Comment: As far as I know, it's still broken and the main SO upload box has changed again.

Comment: @Moshe - k; will try to look